# Start tftpd from shell (as standalone)

Tags: sockets, tftp

I would like to configure and start tftpd from linux shell. 
If I call:

```
tftpd -l -a 127.0.0.0:69 ...
```

I get always:

```
tftpd: stdin is not a socket: Socket operation on non-socket
```

there are no tftp settings in my /etc/services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example solution for embedded can be:

```
# udpsvd -E 0 [PORT] tftpd -c [DIR]
```

Answer (score 0):

For PXE boots the solution in Python with TFTP is https://github.com/psychomario/PyPXE